# Is the differential equation solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(f(t)^2)=a\cdot(b-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(t))$$

where $a, b$ strictly positive constants. I guess this can be integrated to to

$$ f(t)^2 = a\cdot(b\cdot t-\dot f(t))$$

But I do not now how to proceed further. Boundary conditions are:
$$f(0)=0, \dot f(0) = 0$$
If it can not be solved, is there any other ways to analyze it? Specifically, I would need to evaluate $\int_{0}^{t_i} f(t)dt$ for a specific set of $t_i$.

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: $$f(t)\mapsto\frac{\sqrt{3} b \text{Ai}'\left(\frac{b t}{a \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2/3}}\right)+b \text{Bi}'\left(\frac{b t}{a \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2/3}}\right)}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2/3} \left(\sqrt{3} \text{Ai}\left(\frac{b t}{a \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2/3}}\right)+\text{Bi}\left(\frac{b t}{a \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2/3}}\right)\right)}$$
with Ai, Bi the Airy functions.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Also, if possible, some further elaboration on how you reached this result would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's what i have so far: [My solution](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pfeifermaintal/Published/MSE_ODE%20with%20Airy.nb)

Comment: You want to evaluate
$$\int_0^t f(\tau ) \, d\tau=a \log \left(\, _0F_1\left(;\frac{2}{3};\frac{b t^3}{9 a}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Another expression for f(t):

$$f(t) \mapsto \frac{b t^2 \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{5}{3};\frac{b t^3}{9 a}\right)}{2 \, _0F_1\left(;\frac{2}{3};\frac{b t^3}{9 a}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I greatly appreciate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I will use $^{\left[ n. \right]}$ to link to sources for the calculations.*

According to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), the second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation is solvable.
Wolfram|Alpha itself finds a solution in terms of [Airy functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html):[$^{\left[ 1. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdt%28f%28t%29%5E2%29+%3D+a+%E2%8B%85+%28b+-+%28d%5E2%2Fdt%5E2+f%28t%29%29%29)
$$
\begin{align*}
f\left( t \right) &= b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot \frac{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}^{\prime}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}^{\prime}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{2/3}} \right)}{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right)} \tag{1.}\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\operatorname{Ai}$, $\operatorname{Bi}$ are the Airy Functions ($\operatorname{Ai}^{\prime}$ and $\operatorname{Bi}^{\prime}$ are their derivatives) and $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ are constants.

Airy Functions are [Bessel-Type Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/), which means here that we can also replace them with equivalent better-known functions such as the [Generalized Hypergeometric Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) $\operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}$, the [Meijer G-Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html) $\operatorname{G_{p,\, q}^{m,\, n}}$, ..., and the [Bessel Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunction.html) of the [first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $\operatorname{J}$ and the of the [second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $\operatorname{Y}$. With the relation to the Generalized Hypergeometric Functions, you could also represent $f$ as the quotient of two infinite [Gauss's Continued Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction). You can find many of these relations on [The Wolfram Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/).

Wolfram|Alpha also finds an antiderivative of $f$ given by:[$^{\left[ 2. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20%28b%20%28c_2%20Ai%27%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%20%2B%20Bi%27%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%29%29%2F%28%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%20%28c_2%20Ai%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%20%2B%20Bi%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%29%29%20dt)
$$
\begin{align*}
F\left( t \right) &= a \cdot \ln\left( c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) \right) + c_{3} \tag{2.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

With $\int_{b}^{a} f\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t = F\left( a \right) - F\left( b \right)$ and $\left( 2.1. \right)$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{t_{i}} f\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t &= a \cdot \ln\left( c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \frac{b \cdot t_{i} - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \frac{b \cdot t_{i} - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) \right) - a \cdot \ln\left( c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) \right)\\
\int_{0}^{t_{i}} f\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t &= a \cdot \ln\left( \frac{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \frac{b \cdot t_{i} - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \frac{b \cdot t_{i} - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right)}{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right)} \right) \tag{3.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

So we get:
$$\fbox{$\begin{align*}f\left( t \right) &= b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot \frac{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}^{\prime}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}^{\prime}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{2/3}} \right)}{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \frac{b \cdot t - c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right)}\end{align*}$}$$
$$\fbox{$\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{t_{i}} f\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t = a \cdot \ln\left( \frac{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \frac{b \cdot t_{i} - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \frac{b \cdot t_{i} - c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right)}{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right)} \right)\end{align*}$}$$

---

If we use the boundary conditions you mentioned, we can determine $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ exactly. Let's call $f\left( 0 \right) = 0$ Assumption $1$ and $f^{\prime}\left( 0 \right) = 0$ Assumption $2$.

Assuming $1$ gives us:[$^{\left[ 3. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28b%20%28c_2%20Ai%27%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%20%2B%20Bi%27%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%29%29%2F%28%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%20%28c_2%20Ai%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%20%2B%20Bi%28%28b%20t%20-%20c_1%29%2F%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%29%29%29%3D0%20where%20t%3D0)
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= b \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot \frac{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}^{\prime}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}^{\prime}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{2/3}} \right)}{c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( -\frac{c_{1}}{a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \right)}\\
c_{2} &= -\frac{\operatorname{Bi}^{\prime}\left( -\frac{\left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot c_{1}}{b} \right)}{\operatorname{Ai}^{\prime}\left( -\frac{\left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot c_{1}}{b} \right)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Even using the $1$ and $2.$ assumptions, Wolfram|Alpha finds the formula:[$^{\left[ 4. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdt%28f%28t%29%5E2%29%20%3D%20a%20%E2%8B%85%20%28b%20-%20%28d%5E2%2Fdt%5E2%20f%28t%29%29%29%2C%20f%280%29%20%3D%200%2C%20f%27%280%29%3D0)[$^{\left[ 5. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdt%20%28a%20Log%5B%282%20Hypergeometric0F1Regularized%5B2%2F3%2C%20%28b%20t%5E3%29%2F%289%20a%29%5D%29%2F3%5E%281%2F6%29%5D%29)
$$
\begin{align*}
f\left( t \right) &= a \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}^{\prime}\left( \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot t \right) + \operatorname{Bi}^{\prime}\left(  \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot t \right)}{\sqrt{3} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot t \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot t \right)}\\
f\left( t \right) &= \frac{b \cdot t^{2} \cdot \operatorname{_{0}\tilde{F}_{1}}\left( \cdot;\, \frac{5}{3};\, \frac{b}{9 \cdot a} \cdot t^{3} \right)}{3 \cdot \operatorname{_{0}\tilde{F}_{1}}\left( \cdot;\, \frac{2}{3};\, \frac{b}{9 \cdot a} \cdot t^{3} \right)} \tag{4.}\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\operatorname{_{0}\tilde{F}_{1}}$ is the [Kummer's Regularized Confluent Function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1Regularized/02/0001/).

Via using formula $\left( 2. \right)$ we get:[$^{\left[ 6. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20%28a%20%28b%2Fa%29%5E%281%2F3%29%20%28sqrt%283%29%20Ai%27%28%28b%2Fa%29%5E%281%2F3%29%20t%29%20%2B%20Bi%27%28%28b%2Fa%29%5E%281%2F3%29%20t%29%29%29%2F%28sqrt%283%29%20Ai%28%28b%2Fa%29%5E%281%2F3%29%20t%29%20%2B%20Bi%28%28b%2Fa%29%5E%281%2F3%29%20t%29%29%20dt)
$$
\begin{align*}
F\left( t \right) &= a \cdot \ln\left( \sqrt{3} \cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left( \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot t \right) + \operatorname{Bi}\left( \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot t \right) \right) + c_{3}\\
F\left( t \right) &= a \cdot \ln\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt[6]{3}} \cdot \operatorname{_{0}\tilde{F}_{1}}\left( \cdot;\, \frac{2}{3};\, \frac{b}{9 \cdot a} \cdot t^{3} \right) \right) + c_{3} \tag{5}\\
\end{align*}
$$

This gives us:[$^{\left[ 7. \right]}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a%20Log%5B%282%20Hypergeometric0F1Regularized%5B2%2F3%2C%20%28b%20t%5E3%29%2F%289%20a%29%5D%29%2F3%5E%281%2F6%29%5D%29%20where%20t%20%3D%200)
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{t_{i}} f\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t &= a \cdot \ln\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt[6]{3}} \cdot \operatorname{_{0}\tilde{F}_{1}}\left( \cdot;\, \frac{2}{3};\, \frac{b}{9 \cdot a} \cdot t_{i}^{3} \right) \right) - a \cdot \ln\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt[6]{3} \cdot \Gamma\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)} \right) \tag{6.}\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

Answer (score 0):

About how this result can be reached, the equation
$$f(t)^2 = a\cdot(b\cdot t-\dot f(t))$$
that is
$$\dot f(t) = bt-\frac{1}{a}f(t)^2$$
is an [Riccati Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) and can be converted in a linear ODE by the substitution $$f=a\frac{y'}{y}$$
to obtain
$$y''-\frac{b}{a}ty=0$$
which is an [Airy Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).